# How to make odoo progress bar use decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

So I am learning odoo right now, and I want to make the progress bar that use decimal to determine it's percentage. so for example if I input a 0.5, the progress bar will show 50%, so I don't have to input 50 to get 50%.
I tried using options like below

PY

```
progress = fields.Float(string='Progress')
maximum_rate = fields.Float(string='Maximum Rate', default=1)
```

XML

```
<field name="maximum_rate" invisible="1"/>
<field name="progress" widget="progressbar" options="{'max_value': 'maximum_rate', 'editable': True}"/>
```

but the output is either 0/1 or 1/1, it's always on integer value, and it's also not a percentage. so how do I make my progress bar show percentage using decimal value like 0.5 to show 50%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [max_value](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L2853)  is different from `100`, Odoo will compute the value using the following:

```
if (max_value !== 100) {
    this.$('.o_progressbar_value').text(utils.human_number(value) + " / " + utils.human_number(max_value));
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't change this behavior using widget options